# ag-grid change class or change style to RowNode

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to change styles using `NodeRow` object but it does not have access to the element

```js
api.getSelectedNodes().forEach((node)=>{
  if(node.data.isGreen)
    node.rowClass.addClass(['.is-selected-green']) // something like this
})
```

Is there any way to change class using `NodeRow`?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, but not the way you are expecting.

First of all, we cannot access `RowNode`'s DOM programmatically to update its CSS class.

Follow below steps.

1. Set `rowClassRules` property of `gridOptions`.

   ```
   gridOptions.rowClassRules = {
      'is-selected-green': (params) => {
          // try accessing this.otherMethod() here
          return params.data.isGreen;
      }
       // all other classes and their rules
   };
   ```

All the rows having `isGreen` property `true` will be having `is-selected-green` property on it.

2. When you select any row, `ag-row-selected` will be applied to it, so use below CSS to make it look different.

   ```
   .is-selected-green.ag-row-selected {
      // any style
   }
   ```

Comment: In the case that is possible to change the element based on other external context?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Suppose that I have a global object with methods like `globalState`. And I want to change the class rule based on an external state and node data, but data will not change. for example `node.data.x ===1 && globalState.shouldBeRed()`
If I understand It depends on the ag data for updating, but in this case, It depends on an external value, that It could change when the method `shouldBeRed()` chage it's the result

Comment: You can debug and check for that.. I guess as we are using arrow function here, it should be accessible under the function of `rowClassRules`. I've updated the answer. Check

Comment: It works for the first time but It will not update when the method result changes